# Transforming the equation $\cot x -\cos x = 0$ into the form $\cos x(1- \sin x) = 0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

> I am required to write the equation $$\cot x - \cos x = 0$$ 
>   in the form 
>   $$\cos x(1 - \sin x) = 0$$

What I reached is as follows,
\begin{align}
\cot x & = \frac{\cos x}{\sin x}\\[4pt]
\frac{\cos x}{\sin x} - \cos x & = 0\\[4pt]
\cos x\left(\frac{1}{\sin x} - 1\right) & = 0\\[4pt]
\cos x\left(\frac{1}{\sin x} - \frac{\sin x}{\sin x}\right) & = 0
\end{align}

How can I rewrite in the above format?

Comment: You're almost done. Under the assumption that $\sin x \neq 0$, you can remove it from the denominator to obtain $\cos X (1-\sin X) = \sin X \cdot 0 = 0$. If it were zero,  then $\cot X = \infty$, so the statement is not possible.

Comment: How exactly can I remove the sinX

Comment: Take it to the other side, to be multiplied by zero, that's how it's removed. Should I answer the question more clearly.

Comment: Oh I get it thank you very much

Comment: I wrote an answer anyway. I  want to make sure you are satisfied.

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/users/173070/n-f-taussig Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
\cot(X)-\cos(X) =  0 \implies \frac{\cos X}{\sin X} - \cos X = 0 \implies \cos X\bigg(\frac{1}{\sin X} - 1\bigg) = 0
$$
$$
\implies \frac{\cos X(1 - \sin X)}{\sin X} = 0 \implies \cos X(1 - \sin X) = 0 \cdot \sin X = 0
$$

This applies when $\sin X \neq 0$. If it is zero, then $\cot X = \infty$ so the equation is not satisfied.